# Calling jQuery extension stops for loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, for-loop

So I wrote a jquery plugin that turns select elements into a styleable div and ul with the same functionality.  I was previous calling each select element individually, like so:

```
$("#myElementId").selectList();
```

But now I've decided that I want to be able to add the "selectList" class to a select list and then loop over all of the elements with the selectList class and turn them into the dynamic element, like so:

```
var selects = $(".selectList");
for (i=0,j=selects.length;i<j;i++){
    $(selects[i]).selectList();
}
```

Which works fine, but only for the first element.  For some reason, once .selectList() gets called, it ends my for loop and it never proceeds to the next iteration.  I have no idea why.  I have verified that `$(".selectList")` is indeed longer than 1, and if I put nothing in the loop except `console.log(selects[i])` I get a log of each element as expected.  It's not until I call my extension on one of them that it stops the loop.

Can somebody please explain this behavior to me?

Here's my plugin code if you need it.  Please do not redistribute or reuse with crediting me in the comments of the js file:

```
// Custom select element functionality.
jQuery.fn.selectList = function(){

// Grab the original select element and it's options
var originalSelect = this;
var originalOptions = originalSelect.children("option");
var originalId = originalSelect.attr("id");

// Set the original select item to be hidden
originalSelect.css({"display": "none !important"});

// Set up our replacement block
var newContainer = "<div class='selectList_container' id='" + originalId + "_selectList' tabindex='0'>" + 
                      "<p class='selectList_value'>" + $(originalOptions[0]).html() + "</p>" + 
                      "<div class='selectList_optionsWrapper' style='height: 0 !important'>" + 
                         "<ul class='selectList_options' style='display: none;'></ul>" + 
                      "</div>" + 
                   "</div>";

// Append it to the original container
$(newContainer).insertAfter(originalSelect);

// Set up our new variables.  All references from here on in the script will reference the existing element already added to the document.
newContainer = $("#" + originalId + "_selectList");
var newValue = newContainer.find(".selectList_value");
var newList = newContainer.find(".selectList_options");
var newItems;

// Function to toggle the list
var toggleList = function(){
    newList.toggle();
};

// Create our options and add them to our new list
for (i=0, j=originalOptions.length; i<j; i++){

    // Get original option values
    var thisOption = $(originalOptions[i]);
    var optionText = thisOption.html();
    var optionValue = thisOption.val();

    // Build out our new item
    var newItem = "<li name='" + optionValue + "'";

    // Add a class of first and last to the first and last options to aid in styling
    if (i == 0) {
        newItem += " class='first' ";
    } else if (i == (j-1)){
        newItem += " class='last' ";
    };

    // Close out our new item
    newItem += ">" + optionText + "</li>";

    // Add our new item to the newItems string to be added to the dom later
    newItems += newItem;
};

// Add our new item to the list we've made
$(newItems).appendTo(newList);

// Reference to the new list items
var newOptions = $("#" + originalId + "_selectList .selectList_options li");

// Default CSS values for our new dom elements
newContainer.css({position: "relative"});
newValue.css({cursor: "pointer", display: "block", "text-align": "left"});
newList.css({margin: "0 auto", "z-index": "9999999"});
newOptions.css({cursor: "pointer", display: 'block'})

// Opens and closes the new select list when the select value is clicked on
newValue.click(toggleList);

// Closes the list if the select element loses focus (mimics default select element behavior).
// In order for this to work, the element the blur event listener is being bound to must have the attribute tabIndex=0.
// This tricks the browser into thinking it is a form element, otherwise blur will not fire.
newContainer.blur(function(){
    // This is in a setTimeout function because of the way IE detects the blur. 
    // 150ms is seamless to the end user but upholds the functionality in IE.
    window.setTimeout(function hide_list(){
        if (newList.is(":visible")) {
            toggleList();   
        };
    },150);
});

// Changes the value of our new select value and activates the old select option when one of our new list items is clicked
for (i=0, j=newOptions.length; i<j; i++) {
    $(newOptions[i]).click(function(){
        var thisText = $(this).html();
        var thisValue = $(this).attr("name");

        newValue.html(thisText).attr({"name": thisValue});
        newList.toggle();
        originalSelect.val($(this).attr("name")).trigger('change');
    });
};

// Make sure if the original select list changes without the use of our new elements, that the new elements stay updated.
this.change(function(){
    newValue.html($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
};
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery's [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)?

Comment: because .each is FAR slower than the traditional for loop in my experience and I am speed freak lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How abt using **$.each** where the current context using this should help..

```
$(".selectList").each(function() {

   $(this).selectList()

});
```

Might be converting it to a DOM element **selects[i]** seems to be creating the problem..

Comment: Using .each() does indeed fix the problem, but I will use this solution as an absolute last resort since I am OCD about not using the .each() function.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [authoring plugin guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). You need to use `this.each` within your plugin to loop over selected elements and return this so as to maintain chainability.

```
$.fn.selectList = function() {  

   return this.each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
   }); 

};
```

Comment: I did this, but for some reason it did not fix the problem.  I will post the new script if it helps.

Comment: @StephenRios But you do understand that both Aziz's and my answer involve the .each() function call that you seem eager to avoid. I understand that you think this is slow, but it is the jQuery recommended way and I can't think of an alternative that wont be hacky unless you build an array of SELECT elements using getElementByTagName() and using a simple FOR loop (not the .each()) and calling your plugin for each item in the array..

Comment: Yes I do.  Thank you for making sure I understood.  Here is the reference for why I am hesitant to use it: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/12

Comment: @StephenRios that's a pretty interesting link! In that case maybe you can use the second approach..

Answer (score 0):

You should apply all your code inside a

```
$.fn.selectList = function() { 
         this.each(function() {
  :
   //your code
   :
         });
}
```

block to ensure it applies to all elements in the selector. In side the each() loop this keyword will give you access to the individual item.

refer: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring